# Get U.S Visa in Malaysia

Tags: visas, usa, malaysian-citizens

I am Malaysian. Does anyone know if I want to travel to the U.S on August 5th, when is the earliest date that I can apply for travel visa? How long does the U.S visa last?

Answer (score 3):

> Nonimmigrant visa applicants are encouraged to apply at least three (3) months 
>   in advance of the intended date of travel. So remember, apply early!
>
> **Visa Processing Time**
>
> Although visa processing time is typically three working days, processing time for specific cases may vary due to individual circumstances and other special requirements.

Source: **[official visa information website of the U.S. Embassy in Kuala Lumpur.](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/my/my-niv-waittimeinfo.asp)**

> How long does the U.S visa last?

Depends upon the **[Visa Type](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/my/my-niv-visatypeinfo.asp)** and a number of other factors, none of which you listed in the question

Comment: Do you mean I can do it before 3 months? Can I apply it now?

Comment: You can apply now. You will list your travel dates in your application and if you're granted a visa it will consider the fact that those travel dates still have a few months to go. They won't say this visa is valid from today up to 3 months when you have to travel after 6 months and they know it.

Comment: What if I haven't buy my flight ticket? Can I apply the Visa for August?